# CloudFlare DNS Overview

Tags: dns, ip, tcp, cloudflare

This is a definitely a high level question so please take that with a grain of salt. I'm using GoDaddy as my registrar to point to my github pages website. I've uploaded the CNAME file and the URL resolves correctly. I've then set up CloudFlare on my site and am confused as to why I need to switch DNS servers to resolve to an IP address. So now, when the root finds the Top Level Domain for .com, will it now point to the CloudFlare DNS vs the GoDaddy one? In effect am I now just paying GoDaddy for the address and allowing CloudFlare to resolve the IP from the Top Level Domain Servers? Just trying to get an idea of what the CloudFlare DNS server is actually doing and why I had to switch out the GoDaddy one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFlare is taking over managing the DNS for the domain when you switch to our nameservers (GoDaddy is still your registrar/host). CloudFlare works via authoritative DNS.